# Knockout click data binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an issue in below example

**HTML CODE**:

```
 <table id="items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ToDo List</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: toDoItems">
        <tr>
            <td><label data-bind="text: toDoItem"></label></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeToDoItem">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Add item: <input type="text" id="newitem" />
<button data-bind="click: addnewItem">Add</button>
```

**This is my JS code**:

```
$(function () {

  var MetalViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.toDoItems = ko.observableArray();

    self.update = function() {
        self.toDoItems.removeAll();
        self.toDoItems.push(
            new metals({"Task":"This is urgent task."}),
            new metals({"Task":"You need to do it also."})
        );
    }
    self.addnewItem = function () {
        alert( $("#newitem").val() );
        self.toDoItems.push(
            new metals({"Task":$("#newitem").val()})
        );
    };
    self.removeToDoItem = function(item) {
        self.toDoItems.remove(item);
    };

  };

var MetalViewModel = new MetalViewModel();
var y = window.setInterval(MetalViewModel.update,1000);
ko.applyBindings(MetalViewModel, document.getElementById("items"));

});
var metals = function (data) {
    return {
        toDoItem: ko.observable(data.Task)
    };
};
```

Everything is working fine. Listing, removing ....

The only issue I am facing is that when I add new item, function is totally not working... means even if I alert click binding does not reach there.

Comment: Can you create a demo/jsfiddle link? As for issue #2, apparently, is expected behavior unless the state of the your model is saved between http requests.

Comment: `var MetalViewModel = new MetalViewModel();` <= you should chose another name for your instance, like `var myModel = new MetalViewModel();`

Comment: Please check whether you have closed all braces properly. Kindly create a fiddle. It will help people to identify the root cause faster

Comment: in order to call <data-bind="click: addnewItem">, Why "addnewItem" cannot be the part of existing model? Can you please explain?

Comment: I think the GôTô has explained it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bound only the table with your vewmodel (`id=items`):

```
 ko.applyBindings(MetalViewModel, document.getElementById("items"));
```

And your button is outside the table so it is not related to your viewmodel.

As a solution, you can bind to the common parent or to the whole page:

```
 ko.applyBindings(MetalViewModel);
```

Comment: Yes you are right, on your opinion. Actually I cannot remove binding ID from table as I will have multiple data bindings in one template. So another hint is good that I had to take my button into the ID table. It worked :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here're two issues:

- invalid binding, instead of `ko.applyBindings(MetalViewModel, document.getElementById("items"));` should be `ko.applyBindings(MetalViewModel);`
- invalid `data-bind` function name instead of `additemToAdd` should be `addToDoItem`

here's working [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/eMUAL/8/)